# Insert canvas inside div with js

Tags: javascript

I have this part of code

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
let windowWidth = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
let windowHeight = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.id = 'canvas';
document.body.insertBefore(canvas, document.body.firstChild);
```

problem is that i am unable to add it inside a div for example `<div class="ip_first_block">CANVAS SHOULD BE HERE</div>`
I am really on beginning of my js path so i am mostly putting togehter parts and editing them.

This is the part a need to change but i cant find the right way

```
document.body.insertBefore(canvas, document.body.firstChild);
```

This is one of my tries...

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var firstblock = document.getElementsById('ifb');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var windowWidth = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
var windowHeight = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.id = 'canvas';
firstblock.innerHTML += canvas;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`canvas` is an element and not a string. You should use the proper API to append it as a child:
`firstblock.appendChild(canvas)`

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')

  var container = document.querySelector('.ip_first_block')

  container.appendChild(canvas)

})
```

Comment: Thank very much. It works. I can accept answer in 8 minutes.